# After updating I got these error messages

Tags: updating

After updating my Drupal 8 test site from 8.3.7 to 8.4.0, I got these error messages:

> Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
>   The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
>
> #### Webform submission
>
> - The Sprache field needs to be updated.
>
> #### Absatz
>
> - The Veröffentlicht field needs to be updated.
> - The Behavior settings field needs to be updated.

What do I have to do? I don't know how and where I should update these fields. Should I update any database table, or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try on terminal this command

```
drush entity-updates
```

Or if you have [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, you can also use the "Execute PHP Code" page at http;//example.com/devel/php

```
try {
  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->applyUpdates();
}
catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
  print_r($e);
}
```